# Is the & (Address in Memory) an operator in Swift or am I using C?

Tags: swift, ampersand

So I am working through Ales Tsurko great [and needed] Swift conversions of Chris Adamson's CoreAudio example.  However, I have come across something I cannot seem to find straight answer for.

In the examples there is something like this:

```
    var theErr = noErr
    var dictionarySize: UInt32 = 0
    var isWritable: UInt32 = 0
    theErr = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(
            audiofile, 
            kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, 
            &dictionarySize, 
            &isWritable
    )
```

What I am curious about is the use of '&' (ampersand) operator.

Now in the normal C-Family of languages this refers to the memory address of a variable and it seems to be doing that here.

What and I am confused about is am I writing Swift or C code in the fourth line?

I know know you mix Obj-C and Swift, but I cannot find anything in the Swift Documentation of the use of the & as a memory operator.  So is this use undocumented, or if I have temporary stepped out of Swift into C/Obj-C with that line?

Thanks

Comment: This is not about C.

Comment: Lookup "inout parameters" or search for "ampersand" in the Swift books, it *is* documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Apple documentation on Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html):

> When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeMutablePointer
>   argument, it can accept the same operands as
>   UnsafeMutablePointer for any type Type.
>
> If you have declared a function like this one:
>
> ```
> func takesAMutableVoidPointer(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)  {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> You can call it in any of the following ways:
>
> ```
> var x: Float = 0.0, y: Int = 0
> var p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = nil, q: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = nil
> var a: [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], b: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(nil)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(p)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(q)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(&x)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(&y)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(&a)
> takesAMutableVoidPointer(&b)
> ```

So that's passing the address of an object to a function, and is native Swift.

Comment: Ok I get it now.  That makes sense, for some reason I didn't get the connection.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to use the & operator on a constant? (let x = …)

Comment: @bio A constant doesn't necessarily have an address.  `let a = 3` doesn't likely store 3 anywhere, it is just substituted in wherever `a` is used.